# Do I NEED to use move_uploaded_file() function?

Tags: php, file-upload

Am I enforced in some way to use `move_uploaded_file()` and/or delete the temporary file?

My application needs only to load the file contents in memory (eg. via `file_get_contents()`). Do I need to move it to another directory before? Otherwise, am I required to delete it at the end of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in cases when `open_basedir` or `safe mode` (hopefully `safe_mode` will go out of style eventually) otherwise prevent you to read from the location the uploaded file was saved to. The `move_uploaded_file()` is aware of those restrictions but only enforce them to the second parameter, so you can move files out of lets say `/tmp/` while otherwise you couldn't read that directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to save the uploaded file somewhere, you don't need to use `move_uploaded_file()`. Read from the file however you like; it'll be deleted automatically by PHP at the end of the request.